# React Native Using Jar Library for IOS

Tags: react-native

I have a bluetooth thermal printer it only comes with SDK that support android os (said in the manual) in JAR file. Since react native are able to use JAR libs, it is possible to use it for IOS as well?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no, really long answer yes.
Technically you can use tools like https://github.com/google/j2objc to transform code to Objective-C or even more complicated things like (which are rather meant to be used instead of RN )

https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine?utm_source=Develop+Blog+http://www.develop-online.net/&utm_medium=Text+Link&utm_campaign=Android_EMEA_Q1-16_Developer-Blog_Blog-Page?08032016

and only logic layer http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf-mobile/overview/index.html

The problem doesn't lie in RN itself. it is more of how iOS normally doesnt have JVM so you need to get around of it. and RN can use JARs normally for Android only. So it is quite longer way to go around (transform file with j2objc and then use it would be probably the fastest).